# pyspark rdd/dataframe not creating table in cassandra automatically

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cassandra, rdd, spark-cassandra-connector

After checking all sources found datastax-spark-cassandra connector supports automatic creation of table in cassandra with rdd in scala and java. For pyspark specifically another package is available to do this job -- https://github.com/anguenot/pyspark-cassandra. But even with this package unable to create table automatically. With dataframe I didn't found any option at all. Am new to pyspark and cassandra, any help is highly appreciated.  Tried using only anguenot package as dependency as well.
Spark version : 2.4.7
Cassandra : latest docker image

```
Pyspark shell >> pyspark --packages anguenot/pyspark-cassandra:2.4.0,com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.5.1
>>> spark = SparkSession.builder.master('local[*]').appName('cassandra').config("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "ip").config("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "port").config("spark.cassandra.auth.username", "username").config("spark.cassandra.auth.password", "password").getOrCreate()
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> rdd = sc.parallelize([{
...     "key": k,
...     "stamp": datetime.now(),
...     "tags": ["a", "b", "c"],
...     "options": {
...             "foo": "bar",
...             "baz": "qux",
...     }
... } for k in ["x", "y", "z"]])

>>> rdd.saveToCassandra("test", "testTable")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'RDD' object has no attribute 'saveToCassandra'
```

Comment: do you have a hard requirement for Spark 2.4? or you can upgrade to Spark 3?

Comment: will check Spark3

Answer (score 3):

Generally, it's possible to create tables from Spark Cassandra Connector for RDDs ([saveAsCassandraTable or saveAsCassandraTableEx](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/b2.5/doc/5_saving.md#saving-rdds-as-new-tables)) or Dataframes ([createCassandraTable and createCassandraTableEx](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/b2.5/doc/14_data_frames.md#creating-a-new-cassandra-table-from-a-dataset-schema)), but this functionality is available only in Scala API.

Since version 3.0, Spark Cassandra Connector [supports Catalogs API](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/b3.0/doc/14_data_frames.md#catalogs) (Spark 3+), so you'll be able to work with keyspace & tables (create/alter/drop) using the Spark SQL, like this:

```py
spark.sql("""
CREATE TABLE casscatalog.ksname.testTable (
     key_1 Int, key_2 Int, key_3 Int, 
     cc1 STRING, cc2 String, cc3 String, value String) 
  USING cassandra
  PARTITIONED BY (key_1, key_2, key_3)
  TBLPROPERTIES (
    clustering_key='cc1.asc, cc2.desc, cc3.asc'
  )
""")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should import `pyspark_cassandra` before creating rdd:

```
>>> import pyspark_cassandra
>>> rdd = sc.parallelize(...)
>>> rdd.saveToCassandra("test", "testTable")
```

See https://github.com/anguenot/pyspark-cassandra#examples.

Comment: Tried that earlier forgot to add here, that gives below error >  java.io.IOException: Couldn't find test.testTable or any similarly named keyspace and table pairs. From this I understand anyways we cannot create table automatically. Am I correct ?  @Aleksandr Sorokoumov

Comment: Not sure if creating tables automatically from RDD is possible. For example, Spark wouldn't be able to guess what fields should become a primary key.